# Calling an overloaded constructor of superclass in Java

Tags: java, inheritance, constructor

In java, can a contructor in a class call an overloaded constructor of its 
superclass (say if we wanted to make that call explicitly and 
deliberately).

I know that a constructor in a class makes implicit call to 
no-arg default constructor of superclass (with `super();`). But suppose I 
make a call to an overloaded superclass constructor (say `super(String s);`), then my question is, Is this possible? And if this is possible, then 
is a call to `super()` still made ahead of `super(String s)` or not and what 
are its implications?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can call an overloaded constructor of the superclass. And that should be the **first** statement inside the constructor.

And no, you can only invoke the superclass's constructor once, so a call to `super(args)` would substitute the implicit call to `super()`. For the example:

### A.java

```
public class A {
    private String fieldA;

    public A(String a) {
        fieldA = a;
    }
}
```

### B.java

```
public class B extends A {
    private int fieldB;

    public B(String a, int b) {
        // Call the overloaded constructor of the class A
        super(a); // replaces the implicit call to super()
        fieldB = b;
    }
}
```

but if you do this, you will get an error because the call to `super()` is not the first statement of the constructor:

```
public B(String a, int b) {
    fieldB = b;
    super(a); // Call to super() must be first statement in constructor body
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> Yes, we can override super-class's constructor call,  while override
>   super-class's default constructor call it will not skip/avoid to call
>   default constructor call.

**Refer this code and kindly see output,**

```
Class A{
  A(){
        System.out.println("A-Default");
  }
  A(String msg){
     System.out.println("A-With one Argument msg : " + msg );
  }
}
public Class B extends A{
    B(){
             super("Hi");  
             System.out.println("B-Default");
    }

    public static void main(String [] args){
          new B();
    }

}

Output : 

A-With one Argument msg : Hi
B-Default
```

Answer (score 0):

in multilevel inheritance in java we use **super** keyword.

I have made a small example so you understand the flow of execution of a super constructor when used in inheritance.

```
***Calling Default Super Constructor***

    class A {

    public int a ;
    public int aa ;
    A(){
       this.a = 20 ;
        System.out.println("Constructor of class A is called") ;
    
    }
    A(int aa){
    
        this.aa = aa ;
        System.out.println("Parameterized Constructor of class A is called") ;
    }
    
    

}

class B extends A{

    public int b ;
    public int bb ;
    B(){
    this.b = 20 ;
        System.out.println("Constructor of class B is called") ;
    }
    B(int bb){
    
        this.bb = bb ;
        System.out.println("Parameterized Constructor of class B is called") ;
    }

}

class C extends B{

    public int c ;
    public int cc ;
    C(){
        this.c = 30 ;
        System.out.println("Constructor of class C is called") ;
    
    }
    
    C(int cc){
    
        this.cc = cc ;
        System.out.println("Parameterized Constructor of class C is called") ;
    }


}

class MultiLevel{

    public static void main(String args[]){
    
        new C() ;
    
    }

}
```

***Output***

[image: Default constructor called]

```
***Calling Parameterized Super Constructor***

class A {

    public int a ;
    public int aa ;
    A(){
       this.a = 20 ;
        System.out.println("Constructor of class A is called") ;
    
    }
    A(int aa){
    
        this.aa = aa ;
        System.out.println("Parameterized Constructor of class A is called") ;
    }
    
    

}

class B extends A{

    public int b ;
    public int bb ;
    B(){
    this.b = 20 ;
        System.out.println("Constructor of class B is called") ;
    }
    B(int bb){
        super(33) ;
        this.bb = bb ;
        System.out.println("Parameterized Constructor of class B is called") ;
    }

}

class C extends B{

    public int c ;
    public int cc ;
    C(){
        this.c = 30 ;
        System.out.println("Constructor of class C is called") ;
    
    }
    
    C(int cc){

        super(22) ;
    
        this.cc = cc ;
        System.out.println("Parameterized Constructor of class C is called") ;
    }


}

class MultiLevel{

    public static void main(String args[]){
    
        new C(55) ;
    
    }

}
```

***Output***

[image: Parameterized Constructor Called]

***Conclusion***

If you call default super() constructor in child ==> It will call default Constructor of immediate Parent Class

If you call parameterized super(Param) constructor in child ==> It will call the Parameterized constructor of Parent class.

But which parent in multilevel inheritance ?

Ofcourse, the immediate parent.

Comment: Learn more about java inheritance here :

Comment: https://www.educative.io/blog/java-inheritance-tutorial